# Javascript only detection of "Do not track" settings in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I would like to respect the DNT settings in all browsers using only javascript (I don't have server side access to the host server).  I got the following from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947583/266960

```
var isDNT = navigator.doNotTrack == "yes" || navigator.doNotTrack == "1" || navigator.msDoNotTrack == "1";
```

This works in all browsers but IE11 (specifically 11.0.9600.16428 run through  [http://spoon.net/]), which does not seem to honour any of the above BOM properties (I tried setting the DNT preference via the Internet Options > Advanced > Security: "Always send a do not track header" and also via Safety > Turn on tracking protection).

Can anyone else confirm this is correct (i.e. a bug in IE11), or suggest a JS only method to detect those settings?

TIA
Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per this [answer from Microsoft](https://twitter.com/adrianba/status/476586085422600192):  "The standard was updated" as of IE11, placing the `doNotTrack` property on the `window` object instead.

Not all browsers are up to date with this yet, only IE11 and Safari 6.1.1+ have updated at this time as per this [window properties table](http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/de/home?&property=doNotTrack).

As of this writing there is a current [disagreement/discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1023920#c2) from Mozilla as to whether doNotTrack should be a window or navigator property.

Comment: Thanks Hexalys - sounds likely - I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `window.external.msTrackingProtectionEnabled()`, which returns a boolean and is implemented in IE 9/10. I cannot test right now, but it's probably supported in IE 11 as well.

http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/Browser/DoNotTrack/Default.html

Comment: Interesting - that accurately reflects the setting in Tracking Protection (i.e. returns true when enabled), however it remains false (as you'd expect really) when the Safety > Turn on tracking protection is enabled. I suspect MS have overlooked implementing the BOM property for their UI setting, thus making the "DNT" setting only detectable via the headers (so not in JS)

Comment: @MrBen Perhaps you are right that it might be a bug then. Should there really be a difference between Tracking Protection and Safety > Turn on tracking protection? Aren't both supposed to do the same thing? Just asking, I never really heard of that setting until now.

Comment: I've marked this as correct since it seems this is the only way to infer tracking protection preference in IE11 until navigator.doNotTrack is fixed! Unless anyone can put me straight...